# Configure open PDF's in app (acrobat) for Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, document, pdf

When trying to open a pdf document directly from SharePoint online the only option is to open in web.

When we try to open any word or excel files it gives the option to open in app.

How do we enable/configure this option for pdf?

Comment: i found this but im not too sure this will do as im asking. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#newpdfreaderenabled

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

Open in App (Desktop client) option is only available for Microsoft Office files like word, excel, PowerPoint, etc.

You cannot customize SharePoint default "Open" menu to add additional options.

Comment: Individual users may achieve this using browser settings or Acrobat PDF viewer settings. Check if it helps: https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/hub/how-to/why-pdfs-open-in-browser.html